# Training of hiddens layer don't improve accuracy

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning

I've been programming this neural network composed of 4 layers:

The first one with 2 neural, second with 2, third with 2 and the output one with one neurons 
I made this schema to show what I'm trying to reproduce :

[image]

Here is the code, you can try to run it (python 3.7) :

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#Calculus of the sigmoid
def sigmoid(z):
    return 1.0/(1+ np.exp(-z))

#Calculus of the sigmoid derivation
def sigmoid_derivative(y):
    return y * (1.0 - y)

#Initialisation of the class (input, output, targets, weights, biais)
class NeuralNetwork:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.input      = x
        self.weights1   = np.random.rand(self.input.shape[1],2)
        self.weights2   = np.random.rand(2,2)
        self.weights3   = np.random.rand(2,2)
        self.weights4   = np.random.rand(2,1)
        self.y          = y
        self.output     = np.zeros(self.y.shape)
        self.bias1      = np.random.rand(1,2)
        self.bias2      = np.random.rand(1,2)
        self.bias3      = np.random.rand(1,2)
        self.bias4      = np.random.rand(1,1)
        self.learning_rate = 0.005

    #simple feed forward
    def feedforward(self):
        self.layer1 = sigmoid(np.dot(self.input, self.weights1) + self.bias1)
        self.layer2 = sigmoid(np.dot(self.layer1, self.weights2) + self.bias2)
        self.layer3 = sigmoid(np.dot(self.layer1, self.weights3) + self.bias3)
        self.output = sigmoid(np.dot(self.layer2, self.weights4) + self.bias4)

    #Back propagation algorithme
    def backprop(self):

        # application of the chain rule to find derivative of the loss function with respect to weights4, weights3, weights2, weights1 and the associated bias
        delta_4 = 2*(self.y - self.output) * sigmoid_derivative(self.output)
        d_weights4 = np.dot(self.layer3.T, delta_4)
        d_bias4 = delta_4
        d_bias4 = d_bias4.mean(axis=0)

        delta_3 = np.dot(delta_4, self.weights4.T) * sigmoid_derivative(self.layer3)
        d_weights3 = np.dot(self.layer2.T, delta_3)
        d_bias3    = delta_3
        d_bias3    = d_bias3.mean(axis=0)

        delta_2 = np.dot(delta_3, self.weights3.T) * sigmoid_derivative(self.layer2)
        d_weights2 = np.dot(self.layer1.T, delta_2)
        d_bias2    = delta_2
        d_bias2    = d_bias2.mean(axis=0)

        delta_1 =  np.dot(delta_2, self.weights2.T) * sigmoid_derivative(self.layer1)
        d_weights1 =  np.dot(self.input.T, delta_1)
        d_bias1    = delta_1
        d_bias1    = d_bias1.mean(axis=0)

        # update the weights with the derivative (slope) of the loss function
        self.weights1 += d_weights1 * self.learning_rate
        self.weights2 += d_weights2 * self.learning_rate
        self.weights3 += d_weights3 * self.learning_rate
        self.weights4 += d_weights4 * self.learning_rate
        self.bias1    += d_bias1 * self.learning_rate
        self.bias2    += d_bias2 * self.learning_rate
        self.bias3    += d_bias3 * self.learning_rate
        self.bias4    += d_bias4 * self.learning_rate

    def cost(self):
        return np.mean((self.output - self.y)**2)


if __name__ == "__main__":

    #Number of rows per class
    row_per_class = 200
    #generate rows

    #Creating a data set hard to resolve
    sick_people =  (np.random.randn(row_per_class,2))
    row_sick = int(row_per_class/8)
    healthy_people =  2*(np.random.randn(row_sick,2)) + np.array([0,10])
    healthy_people2 = 2*(np.random.randn(row_sick,2)) + np.array([0,-10])
    healthy_people3 = 2*(np.random.randn(row_sick,2)) + np.array([10,0])
    healthy_people4 = 2*(np.random.randn(row_sick,2)) + np.array([-10,0])
    healthy_people5 =  2*(np.random.randn(row_sick,2)) + np.array([10,10])
    healthy_people6 = 2*(np.random.randn(row_sick,2)) + np.array([10,-10])
    healthy_people7 = 2*(np.random.randn(row_sick,2)) + np.array([-10,10])
    healthy_people8 = 2*(np.random.randn(row_sick,2)) + np.array([-10,-10])
    features = np.vstack([sick_people, healthy_people2, healthy_people, healthy_people3, healthy_people4, healthy_people5, healthy_people6, healthy_people7, healthy_people8])
    targets = (np.concatenate((np.zeros(row_per_class), np.zeros(row_per_class)+1)))

    #To have a good vision of the dataset created just above
    plt.scatter(features[:,0], features[:,1], c=targets, cmap = plt.cm.Spectral)
    plt.show()
    targets = targets[np.newaxis].T

    #Initialing the neural network
    nn = NeuralNetwork(features,targets)

    #Test without training, we can see the current accuracy
    nn.feedforward()
    predictions = np.around(nn.output)
    print ("Accuracy", np.mean(predictions == nn.y))

    #Training part
    for i in range(30000):
        if i  % 1000 == 0:
            print (nn.cost())
        nn.feedforward()
        nn.backprop()

    # Re Testing of the feedforward after the training
    nn.feedforward()
    predictions = np.around(nn.output)
    print ("Accuracy", np.mean(predictions == nn.y))
    predictions = np.around(np.squeeze(np.asarray(nn.output)))

    #Show on graph how well the training went
    plt.scatter(features[:,0], features[:,1], c=predictions, cmap = plt.cm.Spectral)
    plt.show()


    # It allows us to have a better vision of the result, we project random point by thousands and
    # see the graph

    row_per_class = 2000
    #generate rows
    sick_people =  (np.random.randn(row_per_class,2))*4
    sick_people2 =  (np.random.randn(row_per_class,2))*4
    healthy_people = (np.random.randn(row_per_class,2))*4
    healthy_people2 =  (np.random.randn(row_per_class,2))*4
    features = np.vstack([sick_people,sick_people2, healthy_people, healthy_people2])

    nn.input = features
    nn.feedforward()

    predictions = np.around(np.squeeze(np.asarray(nn.output)))
    plt.scatter(features[:,0], features[:,1], c=predictions, cmap = plt.cm.Spectral)
    plt.show()
```

It looks like I've respected the mathematic concept of back propagation but the accuracy is never good neither the cost.
It looks like it is random.
Here is the tutorial I have used to make this code (especially the back propagation) :

https://theclevermachine.wordpress.com/2014/09/06/derivation-error-backpropagation-gradient-descent-for-neural-networks/

Thank you so much for your help !

Comment: Do you have a reason for using quite so many hidden layers? Many classification problems don't even need a hidden layer at all, and a single layer is enough to get the job done. You should start with no hidden layers (or 1 if you you definitely know the problem is non-linear -- like the XOR problem), and then add additional hidden layers if you find the ANN is generalising poorly.

Comment: It is just to have a complete understanding of neural network and the mathematics aspect of it

Comment: Your current example looks like it's just got a mass of sick people centred around the origin. Each neuron in the first layer is capable of drawing decision boundary that is a line or plane through the output space. In non-linearly-separable problems you then need a second layer to combine these decision boundaries.  Have a read of this for a good idea of how to construct an ANN and create complex problems for an ANN. https://towardsdatascience.com/beginners-ask-how-many-hidden-layers-neurons-to-use-in-artificial-neural-networks-51466afa0d3e

Comment: In relation to your example problem, it is best solved by an ANN with 1 hidden layer and at least 3 neurons in the hidden layer. That is, you need at least three lines to draw a shape around the central "sick" mass. Each neuron in the hidden layer  creates a decision boundary, like `x < 5`. The output layer can combines the hidden layer to create the final classification. For instance, a 4-neuron hidden layer could produce decision boundaries of `x < 5`, `x > -5`, `y < 5` and `y > -5`. And the output layer can classify the person as "sick" if all 4 neurons in the hidden layer fire.

Comment: But is it normal that it's not working BECAUSE I have too many hidden layer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matrix connections in your feedforward function are wrong

```
#simple feed forward
def feedforward(self):
    self.layer1 = sigmoid(np.dot(self.input, self.weights1) + self.bias1)
    self.layer2 = sigmoid(np.dot(self.layer1, self.weights2) + self.bias2)
    self.layer3 = sigmoid(np.dot(self.layer1, self.weights3) + self.bias3)
    self.output = sigmoid(np.dot(self.layer2, self.weights4) + self.bias4)
```

must be

```
#simple feed forward
def feedforward(self):
    self.layer1 = sigmoid(np.dot(self.input, self.weights1) + self.bias1)
    self.layer2 = sigmoid(np.dot(self.layer1, self.weights2) + self.bias2)
    self.layer3 = sigmoid(np.dot(self.layer2, self.weights3) + self.bias3)
    self.output = sigmoid(np.dot(self.layer3, self.weights4) + self.bias4)
```

I tried your code this way and it seems to work for me
Here is how the prediction looks like
[image]

By the way, not that it makes a big difference but theoretically, you should use a binary cross entropy cost function rather than MSE because your problem here is logistic regression. MSE may make it non-convex that would otherwise be convex.

Comment: Omg, I am so stupid ahah. I was so stuck in my calcul, I didn't even see that ! thank you so much !